# require_once won't read variables from third script

Tags: php

I'm working on some web application, learning PHP OOP. I have 3 scripts: index.php, database.php and config.php.

In config.php are the constants for accessing the DB.

In the database.php is a class for opening and closing the connection to the DB and so on. This file includes the config.php file.

Now on the index file I include the database.php file and I'm testing if `$database` exists. The files `database.php` and `config.php` are in different folder than the `index.php`. 
When I run the `index.php` file it says: `Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER'`

Everything works fine if they are in the same folder. It also works if I include the `config.php` file separately in the index file, but it won't work if only the database file is included

config.php

```
<?php constants ?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
...

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
require_once("../includes/database.php");
...
?>
```

Why won't the index.php file recognize the variables from config.php?

Comment: Do you have another `config.php` in the same folder as `index.php`? what exactly is the path of `config.php`?

Comment: No I don't. 
//includes
     config.php
     database.php
//public
     index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably some problem with the include path. Even though `database.php` and `config.php` are in the same folder, its `index.php` that is making the calls and therefore the include path is the `index.php` folder. When `database.php` attempts to include `config.php` it will be looking for it there.

There are a couple ways you can solve this:

1. Make `index.php` call all the includes, including the `database.php` dependencies;
2. Make `database.php` aware that its path relative to the site root is `../includes` and it too will refer to `config.php` as `../includes/config.php` even though its right there in the same folder with it (not recommended specially if you need `database.php` in subfolders of your site);
3. Use `set_include_path()`. Example:

**index.php:**

```
set_include_path('../includes');
require_once 'database.php';
```

Comment: For the first solution I knew it works. Now I have tried the other two and it also works. I will stick with the second solution. I wasn't looking that way, that even index.php is making the call for config.php. Thanx Havenard

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies with the directories. When you include the `../includes/database.php` file, all paths defined in that file become relative to IT! This means that instead of looking for the configuration file in the directory that index.php is in (lets say `/var/www/html/funfile/index.php`), it's now looking for it in `/var/www/html/includes/` (so the literal path of the include would be `/var/www/html/includes/config.php`). It's a pretty easy fix, just make the path to the config file literal.

Try:

```
require_once("/var/www/html/funfile/config.php");
```

And replace the path I made up, with the actual path to the config file. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should give DB_SERVER in quotes like this:

`define('DB_SERVER',$db_host);
define('DB_USER',$db_user);
define('DB_PASS',$db_pass);
define('DB_NAME',$db_name);`